# Installed iterm2, now both vscode and mac internal terminals are not working

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, iterm2, apple-m1

I installed iterm2 and oh my zsh on my new macbook pro M1. Now I can not use the internal vscode terminal or mac terminal.

**What I have tried:**

I have updated my mac, vscode, iterm2, brew, and oh my zsh.
I am using zsh.
I checked my system preferences/users & groups/unlock/advanced options/login shell: /usr/local/bin/zsh. Which seems correct?

In iterm2 I checked echo $SHELL. (see image)
In iterm2 I checked echo $PATH. (see image)
I ran brew doctor. No issues there.
Checked that I had oh my zsh installed and updated.

[iterm2-shell/path/brew/ohMyZsh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfmkJ.png)

In vscode I have looked at code/preferences/settings/[typed]terminal
checked terminal>integrated>shell: Osx
checked that json file. I don't know what Im looking for there.

[vscode-settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwKbI.png)

**Need Help With:**

In vscode the terminal window does not open now and I get a error message.

[vscode internal terminal error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tatvP.png)

Now that I have iterm2, am I no longer able to use the internal mac terminal? When I go to open the internal mac terminal it is stuck on the following screen.

[Internal mac terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpGkL.png)

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. I am new to the terminal and command line.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does /usr/local/bin/zsh actually exist? If not, you'll need to change it to something that does exist (like maybe /bin/zsh).

Comment: /usr/local/bin/zsh does not exist in vscode terminal and mac internal terminal. To see $SHELL and $PATH for iterm2 see iterm2 link above. How do I make /usr/local/bin/zsh exist and where do I do this? Detailed steps would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to create /usr/local/bin/zsh, just switch your account's shell to "/bin/zsh". You can do this in System Preferences > Users & Groups pane (note: be careful not to change anything else).